# Invalid column when i am not asking for the one

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

My code is:

```
cliente.Country = new List<dic_paises>();

dic_paises C = ((from data in db.dic_paises where data.id == 61  select data).SingleOrDefault());

cliente.Country.Add(new dic_paises() { id = C.id, nome = C.nome });
return View();
```

What I want to do is, I have a table client, and a table countries, now I want to show the clients in the view where instead of showing the id of country stored in client I want to show the country name, it is hard for me to get it done in mvc, because I am new to mvc. Tried to do with view model but did not get what expected.

```
public partial class cliente
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(1024)]
    public string nome { get; set; }

    [StringLength(1024)]
    public string apelido { get; set; }

    [StringLength(1024)]
    public string email { get; set; }

    public List<dic_paises> Country { get; set; }
}
```

That's the client model and here is the countries model:

```
public partial class dic_paises
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(1024)]
    public string nome { get; set; }
}
```

This is what I am doing in my controller, saw a video on youtube ...

```
cliente cliente = db.clientes.Find(id);

if (cliente == null)
{
    return HttpNotFound();
}

cliente.Country = new List<dic_paises>();

dic_paises C = ((from data in db.dic_paises where data.id == 61  select data).SingleOrDefault());

cliente.Country.Add(new dic_paises() { id = C.id, nome = C.nome });
return View();
```

Please help what you can ...

Here is the error ...

> [SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name 'cliente_id'.]
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +2418094
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +5694468
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +285
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +3731
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData() +58
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() +89
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +379
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest) +2064
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite) +375
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method) +53
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) +240
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +41
>
>   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +12
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<Reader>b__c(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c) +14
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch(TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) +72
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +402
>         System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +166
>   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +12
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior) +36
>
> [EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.]
>
> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior) +103
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute(ObjectContext context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues) +758
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.<>c__DisplayClass7.b__6() +90
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction(Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess) +288
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__5() +154
>
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1 operation) +190
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption) +283
>          System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0() +15
>          System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext() +45
>          System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source) +121
>          System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.<GetElementFunction>b__2(IEnumerable`1 sequence) +40
>          System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle(IEnumerable`1 query, Expression queryRoot) +59
>          System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression) +114
>          System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.DbQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression) +116
>          System.Linq.Queryable.SingleOrDefault(IQueryable`1 source) +211
>          WebApplication2.Controllers.clientesController.Details(Nullable`1 id) in C:\Users\dani1\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\Controllers\clientesController.cs:56
>          lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +107
>          System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
>          System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +157
>          System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +22
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d() +50
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +225
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +26
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
>          System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>          System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
>          System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>          System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
>          System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>          System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>          System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
>          System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
>          System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9723757
>          System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

Comment: In your title you talk about Linq2Sql but the question appears to be about entity framework. These are too different technologies. You probably should correct your title.

Comment: Let's start with your cliente model. It contains a List<dic_paises> so you are going to have multiple countries for each cliente? If that's not what you want remove the List part. Then, assuming you configured the relationship correctly, you should be able to get what you want with a command like db.clientes.Include(c => c.Country).SingleOfDefault(c => c.Id == id);

Comment: Where do you use `cliente_id`? Here in codes, there is no `cliente_id`.

Comment: thats what i cant find!?

Comment: i am not using it any where but it shows that

Comment: I tried to adopt steves idea, i think he meant to say this:
cliente = ((from data in db.clientes.Include(c => c.pais).SingleOfDefault(c => c.Id == id) where data.id == 61  select data).SingleOrDefault());
but it is not working, it says,

'IQueryable<cliente>' does not contain a definition for 'SingleOfDefault' and no extension method 'SingleOfDefault' accepting a first argument of type 'IQueryable<cliente>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference

Comment: the error means you mapped the classes wrong. It supposed `dic_paises` has a foreign key of `cliente_id` (the `cliente` class concatenated with its primary key `id`). You need to explicitly map the foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

the situation is resolved like this ...

i guess this is what they call view model

```
public class ClienteCountry
    {
        public cliente cli { get; set; }

        public dic_paises country { get; set; }
    }
```

the controller code ...

```
cliente ccc = (from data in db.clientes where data.id == id select data).FirstOrDefault();
                dic_paises ppp = (from data in db.dic_paises where data.id == ccc.pais select data).FirstOrDefault();
                ClienteCountry cc = new ClienteCountry();
                cc.cli = ccc;
                cc.country = ppp;
                ViewBag.id = id;
                return View(cc);
```

where id is a parameter passed through the view...

in the view i put this ...

```
@model  WebApplication2.Models.ClienteCountry
```

and then i was able to use my properties like this ...

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.cli.nome)
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.cli.nome)

@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.cli.apelido)
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.cli.apelido)

@Html.DisplayName("Country")
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.country.nome)
```

anyway thanks to all of you guys, ...